# Summing among cells across worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to programming so this may be an obvious question. I have a questionnaire asking about drinking habits. I am trying to make an application that will work out the mean etc across all worksheets (participant responses). My code so far allows me to get the total number of worksheets as a number of participant responses but it will only give me the mean for the worksheet that is currently open.What would I need to add to the below code to allow me to get the total mean across all the responses (worksheets).

Code:

```
Function PARTcounter() 'to count the open questionaires

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For I = 1 To WS_Count
TBTOTpar = WS_Count
Next I
End Function

Function SUMwk11() 'finds mean for week 1
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim A As Double
Dim B As Double
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For counter = 0 To WS_Count
Next
A = Application.SUM(Range("c3:i9"))
B = A / 7
TBwk1MEAN = B
End Function
```

Comment: So you need the mean of `C3:I9` across all worksheets? Do you need to do it based on any conditions? Or if you need the mean for week1, do you need that to be input in the function and match the ranges on the sheets? Also - your `for counter next` isn't *doing* anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops don't actually do anything....   You could also do this all in one sub (Not sure why you're using functions). This should do what you want once you've updated the `TBwk1MEAN` to change each loop

```
Sub PARTcounter() 'to count the open questionaires
    TBTOTpar = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub SUMwk11() 'finds mean for week 1
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' You'll need to update this each loop otherwise the mean from each sheet will overwrite the previous one.
        TBwk1MEAN = Application.SUM(ws.Range("c3:i9")) / 7
    Next ws
End Sub
```